# How can I enforce a umodifiable foreign key columnn

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

I have a many-to-one relationship. Let's say a List and it has many Items. It is very important that an item is only present in one list and can never be moved to another list. How would you enforce this by database constraints?

Currently I'm thinking of two alternatives.

1. Create a "many to many" table with an unique constraint on item_id. This would basically be a one-to-one relationship table.
2. Use some kind of trigger to disallow replacement of non-null values in the foreign key column.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Currently Oracle.

Comment: Remove UPDATE DELETE privileges on table from all users but admin

Comment: @Serg The other fields can change. Only the list relationship is immutable.

Comment: Oracle has column level privileges too. But if you allow users to change any content, what is the reason to keep foreign key intact? Essentially  one can just transfer content.